# Convert .htacces to nginx configuration

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I am having issue with converting .htaccess to nginx rules, I tried all the available rules converter online and previously answered questions but no one seems to provide the right solution. I need this because with PHP 8.x Azure Service plan now comes with Nginx instead of Aapache. Here the .htaccess which is perfectly working with Apache, but not on Nginx

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/public.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Any help ?
Thank you

Comment: https://azureossd.github.io/2021/09/02/php-8-rewrite-rule/index.html

Comment: Not working at all, sorry. I Laready tried all the tutorial and online rules converter but without success

Comment: You haven't shown us anything that you've tried.